# Ajax возвращает ошибку 502/500

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите пж-та.
Есть админка, в админке кнопка вкл/выкл которая отправляет в контроллер get запрос. Кнопка работает, функция срабатывает.
Но, если я заменяю прямой get запрос на функцию ajax, в ответ приходит сперва ошибка 502, при повторном нажатии возвращается ошибка 500.
В контроллере стоит функция проверки пользователя из сессии.

```
$(doc).ready(function () {
    $('.prod-category').change(function(event) {
        var ids = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  '/admin-panel/catalog/product/?catId='+ids,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(result) {

                var select = $('.prod-subcategory');
                    select.html('');
                    select.append('<option>Подкатегория товаров</option>');
                $.each(result, function(i){
                    select.append('<option value="' + result[i].cat_subcategory + '">' + result[i].cat_name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ajax тут не причем, это ответ обработки на стороне сервера. Выложите код серверной части?

Comment: Тут ни чего особенного нет:
if(isset($_GET['catId'])){
            echo json_encode(Catalog::getSubCatalog($_GET['catId']));
            return true;
        }
При этом на локальной машине все работает.

Comment: При открытии ссылки в браузере /admin-panel/catalog/product/?catId=1 все работает? Нет 500,502?

Comment: Да, выдает 500.

Comment: Ну, значит надо искать проблему там, к фронтенду (JS,ajax) это не касается. Не ими вызвана данная ошибка.

Comment: Как минимум в куске кода выше заметил `return true;` зачем это? У вас там не функция вроде, чтобы возвращать значение. Если хотели передать таким образом что-то в ответ ajax-у, то этого не нужно делать. Достаточно `echo json_encode(Catalog::getSubCatalog($_GET['catId']));`